# Regular Expression in Javascript for password validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that validates a user's password when they create it. The password needs to be:

1. at least 6 characters long and can be any type of character
2. each character that is used needs to appear in the password exactly 3 times.

Good examples:

```
AAABBB
ABABBA
+++===
+ar++arra
myyymm
/Arrr/AA/
```

Does anyone know which regex would accomplish this?

Comment: Amm... Why EVERY character needs to be repeated 3 times? It makes password weak. `ab` must be converted to `aaabbb` and it's valid, but to hack it you be taking less time...

Comment: I can give you an answer, but please explain first why you would want to have passwords with three times less entropy than necessary...?

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, I'm not quite sure that this can be accomplished with just a regex; definitely not with a JavaScript regex with its very limited capabilities. You'd need two steps: Sort the password first, then use a regex to check that each character occurs exactly three times.

Comment: This is not a great match for regex (and a terrible password scheme). If you're targeting ES6 you can toss all the characters in a map and count them. Less efficiently, you can sort the string and then check it contains runs of 3 (which you could come up with a regex for but it would be more convoluted than almost any other alternative).

Comment: This looks like homework, no one would demand such stupid restrictions on a password

Comment: If it is not homework, it is better to use some time tested password strength checker. Lot of them are available.

Comment: This was a midterm question that no one in my class could solve, so I'm trying to figure out the regex that would make this work. I've been working on it all day but can't come to a solid conclusion, so I was just wondering if anyone could come up with the answer for me to study.

Comment: @sabithpocker - Almost all password strength checkers are obsolete and useless. Nowadays the *conditions for a good password* are **only two**: sufficient length (more is better) and resistance to dictionary attacks (which is the problem itself). Tips as *"use capital an small letters, numbers and special symbols"*  have **no value**, even for average hackers.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with just regex, and no code, in JS since you'd need look-behinds to avoid checking the characters multiple times (which JS don't have).

Comment: @MarianD I have used this [zxcvbn](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/) and looks pretty cool to me although I am not a security person. Is this too bad?

Comment: @sabithpocker - No, it's really, really good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ease yourself by sorting the password before testing it:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
var s = $('#password').val();
var split = s.split("").sort().join("");
if(/^(?:(.)\1{2}(?!\1)){2,}$/.test(split))
   console.log("Valid password");
else
   console.log("Invalid password");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password">
<button>Test me</button>
```

Comment: this doesn't account for the overall length of 6 characters, correct?

Comment: minimum of 6 not exactly 6 :)

Comment: :) @ThomasAyoub

Comment: This will validate passwords like `AAAAAA` - it only checks for multiples of threes, not *exactly* three instances of each character.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st option you have to check without regex.

```
var str = "your password";
var pattern = /(.)(.*\1){3}/;
if(str.length >= 6){
   // It will give you boolean as return
   // If it is match then it return true else false
   pattern.test(str);
}
```

Comment: You should try this with some of the test expressions provided.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution since you're allowing code (which your question imply you wouldn't ;)

Using a function like `verifyPass` below should do the trick. It gradually replaces any valid three letter combination with an empty string. Checking that this is done in more than one iteration (it's at least 6 characters) and ending up with an empty string in the end, means it's a valid password.

```js
function verifyPass(pass) {
  var re = /^(.)((?:(?!\1).)*)\1((?:(?!\1).)*)\1((?:(?!\1).)*)$/,
      cnt=0;

  while(re.test(pass)) {
    pass = pass.replace(re, '$2$3$4');
    cnt++;
  }
  return pass==='' && cnt>1;
}

var testItems = [
      '123123123',
      'AAABBB',
      'AAABBBAAA',
      'Qwerty',
      'ABABBA',
      '+++===',
      '111',
      'qweqwd',
      'sdcjhsdfkj',
      '+ar++arra',
      'mYYYmms',
      '/Arrr/AA/'
  ];
  
  testItems.forEach(function(item) {
    document.write('<span style="color:' + (verifyPass(item) ? 'green' : 'red') + ';">' + item + '</span> <br/>');
  });
```